# Flat File Source Component throws error when the flat file is not present in the location

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a Flat File source component inside a Data Flow Task.
At some time when my SSIS package is executing, the required flat file may not be present in the location specified in the Flat File Source Component.

So it is throwing "0x80019002" and the whole package execution fails.
If there a way to restrict this error from stopping the package execution?
We have tried with MaxErrorCount = 2, we are not sure if any other error may occur apart from this. So looking for someother way.

**Actual Error**:
Warning: 0x80019002 at XE Files: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[9100] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: You stated that you are using "SQL Server 2018" in your question (I've removed that as the version should be tagged), however, there is *no such thing* as SQL Server 2018. The latest release version is SQL Server 2019 and the version prior to that was SQL Server 2017; there was no release in 2018. More confusing, you have tagged [[tag:ssis-2012]] which, unsurprisingly, shipped with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: *"So it is throwing "0x80019002""* Show the **entire** error, not just the binary error code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DelayValidation Property to skip the validation.
It is available on package level but also on task & connection level.

Put the dataflow that is using the file in a for each file container. Like this the dataflow using the file is not being executed when there is no file.

Comment: Tried that, but it still throws the same error

Comment: Add also a for each file loop.